# Color format current row depending on value in row above

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I have a bunch of rows with several items of information in each cell.  What I'm trying to do is color format the entire row on 2 conditions:  condition 1... `[column][row] >=100`.  condition 2... `[column][row-1] <100`.  I've seen other examples that do this formatting so it seems possible, and i can get it to work for just that row and i can't get it to format the entire row.  How do I set up the formatting so that I can apply the same thing to every row and have it simply color format the entire row that match the formula

for example... `=and(I551>=1000000,I550<1000000) for range A551:L551` is what I have, but it only color formats the cell in column A, not the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Custom formula** to `=and($I551>=1000000,$I550<1000000)` as depicted below.

[image]

Hope this helps!